# Why does it have to be positive and decreasing to apply the integral test?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The textbook says

> If $f$ is continuous and decreasing for $x\geq1$ and $a_n=f(n)$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ and $\int_1^\infty f(x)dx $ either both converge or diverge.

---

The proof in the book use inscribed rectangles and circumscribed rectangles to make $\{S_n\}$ bounded and monotonic.
I saw some similar questions here but all the counterexamples are about alternating series.
What if I use the same way as the book to proof the theorem,but with increasing,positive and continuous series or function?Or even negative ones?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  If $f$ is positive and increasing, then you don't need the integral test to say it diverges

Comment: @J.W.Tanner thank you for answering.But how about a negative,increasing function,because the book says it must be  a series with positive terms to apply integral test?

Comment: It doesn't "have to be". Instead, it is *sufficient*

Comment: which book is it ?

Comment: @LostInSpace Essential Calculus by Ron Larson 4th edition

Comment: Thank you Savemycalculus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice that your quoted statement does not mention that $f$ is positive.
In fact if $f(x)$ becomes negative for some $x \geq 1,$
and $f$ is continuous and decreasing,
then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ and $\int_1^\infty f(x)\,dx$
both diverge, which agrees with the statement that they both converge or both diverge.
So in fact the condition that $f$ is positive is not necessary;
but if $f$ is *not* positive you can immediately come to a conclusion without looking at the integral.

If $f$ is negative, continuous, and increasing then $-f$ is positive, continuous, and decreasing and $-a_n = -f(n),$ so the theorem you originally quoted to us says that
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty -a_n$ and $\int_1^\infty -f(x)\,dx$
either both diverge or both converge.
But $\sum_{n=1}^\infty -a_n = -\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$
and $\int_1^\infty -f(x)\,dx = -\int_1^\infty f(x)\,dx,$
so $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ and $\int_1^\infty f(x)\,dx$
either both diverge or both converge.

(If you need this to be clearer, first use the theorem to determine that if a function $g$ is positive, continuous, and decreasing and if $b_n = g(n)$ then
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ and $\int_1^\infty g(x)\,dx$
either both diverge or both converge; then substitute $-f$ for $g$ and $-a_n$ for $b_n$.)

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, increasing and positive or negative and decreasing diverges. We can show this through the divergence test.

Even though the formal definition says positive and decreasing, we can pull out a negative in our summation formula and apply the same argument for negative and increasing as well.